# Sum of Salary in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

> Create employee and dept tables for the available files emp1.csv and
> dept.csv.
>
> Colnames: Emp: Empno, name, sal, did, branch, dno
> Dept: deptno, name, loc
>
> Retrieve total salaries to be paid for the employees working in
> ‘chicago’.

the table for emp was like

```
1010,jack,45000,CSE,10
1011,nick,70000,ECE,20
1012,mike,60000,ECE,30
1013,james,25000,CSE,20
```

and dept table was

```
10,ACCOUNTING,DALLAS
20,OPERATIONS,CHICAGO
30,SALES,BOSTON
```

I've joined both tables

```
grunt> emp_data = load ‘student/emp1.csv’ using PigStorage(‘,’) as (empno: int, empname: 
       chararray, sal: int, did: chararray, branch: chararray, dno: int);

grunt> emp_dept = load ‘student/dept.csv’ using PigStorage(‘,’) as (deptno: int, name: 
       chararray, loc: chararray);
grunt> joined = join emp_data by dno, emp_dept by deptno;
grunt> emp_loc = joined by loc matches 'CHICAGO';
grunt> total_sal = foreach emp_loc generate sum(sal);
```

After the last line it shows an error

```
EROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve sum using import: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

The answer should be **95000**

Comment: Capitalization matters. Try `SUM()`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Show error "Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast."

Comment: Not sure about that, but you should filter the dept data by the city before joining

Comment: Usually that error @ArsalanAnsari means that something in your input couldn't be inferred as an int so the SUM function cant work. try casting to int before like (int)sal somewhere, if that fails then check your input or use UDF IsNumeric to filter for only numeric data in sal variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to remove `did: chararray` from the `emp_data` since that doesn't seem to be part of your data.

Regarding the error, capitalization matters for built-in functions. Best to always capitalize all Pig keywords and functions, I've found.

For the "explicit cast" error ... `SUM` (and other aggregate functions) takes a bag, and you are only passing an `int`, thus "none of them fit" (the method signatures of the `SUM` function).
To get a bag, you need to `GROUP`. You can also improve the `JOIN` performance by pre-filtering the data. After the join and group, you need to provide the full identifier of the `sal` (seen from `describe X`)

[From docs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/func.html#sum)

> `SUM`
>
> Computes the sum of the numeric values **in a single-column bag**. `SUM` **requires** a preceding GROUP ALL statement for global sums and **a GROUP BY statement for group sums**

Same logic applies if you were to use SQL...

Example

```
E = LOAD 'emp.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (empno: int, empname: chararray, sal: int, branch: chararray, dno: int);
D = LOAD 'dept.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (deptno: int, name: chararray, loc: chararray);
D_CHI = FILTER D BY loc == 'CHICAGO';

X = JOIN E BY dno, D_CHI BY deptno;

X_BY_LOC = GROUP X BY D_CHI.loc;
O = FOREACH X_BY_LOC GENERATE group, SUM(X.E::sal) as total;
DUMP O;
```

Yes, it is strange to filter then group by when you only have one entry after the filter, but it makes sense if you had more chicago values...

Output

```
(CHICAGO,95000)
```